# Laravel Feature Job Testing No Response

Tags: laravel, testing, webhooks, jobs

I have created webhook API which received payload from the client side

`/api/v1/webhooks/received`

and dispatched the payload in the Job.

Here is my job file.

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class DecisionWebhooksJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(private $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        (new AutoDecisionService())->prepareAutoDecision($this->data);
    }
}
```

Now i have created Test file and testing my Job like

```
public function test_dynamic_decision_webhooks_job_dispatched()
    {
        $payload['data'] = $this->getPayload();

        Bus::fake();
        DecisionWebhooksJob::dispatch($payload);
        $response = Bus::assertDispatched(DecisionWebhooksJob::class);

         return $response; // response not return.
    }
```

Job dispatched but return no any response.

How I verify that my job function `AutoDecisionService())->prepareAutoDecision()` working fine and return response.

Did not get the response from the Test job.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly testing, you are literally faking jobs, so it will never be executed.

And your test is literally trying to do this:

- Get payload for job
- Try executing it
- Making sure it was executed

You see the test makes no sense at all? You are testing if it was run, and of course it will be run because you are literally calling the executing method the line before.

You should have a test that you send whatever data to the API webhook and the job gets executed, that would be the test you are looking for.